# Json decode foreach loop

Tags: php, json, decode

I want to make a foreach loop in my `json` decode script. I'm getting the info of an url, but that url has dynamic script, sometimes there are 4 results and sometimes 10 results.

I have these now:

```
 <?php
 $json = file_get_contents('URL');
 $data = json_decode($json,true);
 ?>

  <strong>Number</strong></a> <?php echo $data['Data'][1]['data']; ?><br />
```

I have now id 1 in my script, but i want alle the id's in my script. Is this possible with foreach oid ?
Else i have to make more rules.

```
 <strong>Number</strong></a> <?php echo $data['Data'][1]['data']; ?><br />
 <strong>Number</strong></a> <?php echo $data['Data'][2]['data']; ?><br />
 <strong>Number</strong></a> <?php echo $data['Data'][3]['data']; ?><br />
```

I googled and checked Stack Overflow but I cant find the solution to my problem.

Comment: Have you _tried_ a `foreach()` loop? show us where you're stuck, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($data['Data'] as $subArray) 
    {
        
        echo"<strong>Number</strong>".$subArray['data']."<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Then i get no output. When i do var_dump subArray i get the following:

array(5) { [0]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> string(2) "37" ["data"]=> string(16) "Henkie"} [1]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["data"]=> string(12) "Jan"

Comment: Need to `foreach($data['Data']`

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes ,you are right. That was my mistake